# How to use 'return' statement?

Tags: python, pandas, return, apply

I'll trying to classify text given a bunch of words in a dictionary, the dictionary contains stemmed groups with different words correlated. And another aspect is that I have a dataframe in which each represen and article.
The main goal is that if at least of 50% of the words in the group were found it, will be assign `1` otherwise `0`.

```
stemmed_search = {Group_1:['solicit', 'requier', 'día'], Group_2:['infraestruc', 'construccion', 'gas', 'nigrogen']}
test = ['solicit', 'requier', 'día', 'infraestruc', 'construccion', 'gas', 'nigrogen']
word_list = [['solicit', 'requier', 'día'], ['infraestruc', 'construccion', 'gas', 'nigrogen']]
def compar(test):
    for item in stemmed_search.values():
        filt = []
        for i in item:
            if i in test:
                filt.append(True)
            else:
                filt.append(False)
        #print(filt)
        umbral = len(filt) * 0.5
        Trues = filt.count(True)

    return[1 if Trues > umbral else 0 for i in range(0, len(words_list))]

text['Class'] = text.Stem.apply(compar)
```

I tried using this statement, but it doesn't work:

```
return[1 if Trues > umbral else 0 for i in range(0,len(filt))]
```

Then I have this: `[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`.
Later suppouse that the problem was in the `range` of the list, so I changed and I had a similar output that was I expected:

```
return[1 if Trues > umbral else 0 for i in range(0, len(words_list))]
```

But when I executed that line the output is very similar that I want: `[1, 1],[1, 1],[0, 0],[0, 0]`.
I think that the problem is here, because when I only execute the comprar function without `apply` it works.

**I expect an output like that** in the `text['Class'] column: [0, 1],[0, 1],[0, 0],[0, 0]`

Comment: Could you provide an example of  input and expected output? Thanks!

Comment: Both inputs ...dictionary of the dataset? or which one?

Comment: at least 'stemmed_search', 'test' and 'filt', if you can do the rest better

Comment: Is that better?

Comment: I think you first need to decide if you want to print things, or you want to create a column in a `pandas` dataframe, because it doesn't make sense to call a function by `pandas.apply()`, when all it does is to print numbers and "END ROW".

Comment: Of course yes, I know it. This is only for debugging

Comment: compar(test) return [1,1]. Is it the output you expect?

Comment: No, It would be [0,1], [0,1], [0,0],[0,0]

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your problem correctly, given the following input:

```
stemmed_search = {'Group_1':['solicit', 'requier', 'día'], 'Group_2':['infraestruc', 'construccion', 'gas', 'nigrogen']}
test = ['solicit', 'requier', 'día', 'infraestruc', 'construccion', 'gas', 'nigrogen']
test2 = ['solicit', 'lol', 'lol', 'infraestruc', 'construccion', 'gas', 'nigrogen']

df = pd.DataFrame([[test,test2]], ['Stem']).T
                                                Stem
0  [solicit, requier, día, infraestruc, construcc...
1  [solicit, lol, lol, infraestruc, construccion,...
```

This code is for you:

```
def compar2(test):
    test = set(test)
    return [1 if len(set(group) - test) < len(group) * 0.5 else 0 for _,group in stemmed_search.items()]

df['Text'] = df.Stem.apply(lambda x: compar2(x))
```

And gives:

```
                                            Stem      Text
0  [solicit, requier, día, infraestruc, construcc...  [1, 1]
1  [solicit, lol, lol, infraestruc, construccion,...  [0, 1]
```

**EDIT**: Other example:

```
def category_name(test):
    return [k for k,group in stemmed_search.items() if len(set(group) - set(test)) < len(group) * 0.5]

stemmed_search = {'Food': ['pizza', 'chips', 'cheese', 'tomato', 'apple'], 
                  'Animal': ['horse', 'snake', 'dog', 'cat'],
                  'School': ['book', 'pen', 'vocabolary', 'homework', 'student']
                 }
stemmed_articles = [['macheroni', 'car', 'pizza', 'free', 'dog', 'apple', 'chips'],
                    ['dog', 'hungry', 'cat', 'kill', 'snake', 'gas', 'apple'],
                    ['student', 'train', 'car', 'pen', 'homework', 'table', 'book']
                   ]

df = pd.DataFrame([stemmed_articles], ['stemmed_articles']).T
df['categories'] = df.stemmed_articles.apply(lambda x: compar2(x))
df['categories_name'] = df.stemmed_articles.apply(lambda x: category_name(x))
```

And gives:

```
                                    stemmed_articles categories  categories_name  
0   [macheroni, car, pizza, free, dog, apple, chips]  [1, 0, 0]  [Food] 
1        [dog, hungry, cat, kill, snake, gas, apple]  [0, 1, 0]  [Animal] 
2  [student, train, car, pen, homework, table, book]  [0, 0, 1]  [School]
```

Comment: The problem is: I have dataframe with a column a 'n' numbers of rows, each row represent an article. In the other hand I have a dictionary with differrent topics. So, I have to check whichs aricles match in at least of the 50%...if is True obtain `1` otherwise `'0`. For every key in the dictionary.

Comment: that's exactly what this code does :) tag article1 in topic1 and topic2, tag article2 in topic2 @ChachoFuva

Comment: @ChachoFuva is it clear or do you want me to give you another example?

Comment: @ChachoFuva I added another example, I hope I have clarified your doubts

Comment: Thanks. Could you explain me what does group?

Comment: @ChachoFuva `group` is the value of the dict `stemmed_search`. For example for the key `'Animal'` `group` is `['horse', 'snake', 'dog', 'cat']`